# Game event loop for multi-threaded application

Tags: c++, game

My take on this problem for a hobby project.

I have an event loop that advances game state and processes user input.

Rendering is no concern of this event loop, and is intended to run on a separate thread.

The event loop is GUI agnostic and works with a generic `GameLogic` that must comply with a certain interface.

Any feedback is appreciated, either about specific parts of the code or overall design.

The event loop:

```
template<typename GameLogic>
class EventLoop {
public:

    using GameLogicType = GameLogic;
    using StateType = typename GameLogic::StateType;
    using EventType = typename GameLogic::EventType;
    using StateStoreType = StateStore<StateType>;

    explicit EventLoop(const GameLogicType &gameLogic) : _gameLogic{std::move(gameLogic)} {

    }

    void run() {

        auto durationFromStart = [realTimeStart = ClockType::now()]() {
            return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(ClockType::now() - realTimeStart);
        };

        int simulationSteps{0};
        auto state = _gameLogic.initialState();

        for (;;) {

            while ((simulationSteps * framePeriod) < durationFromStart()) {
                std::vector<EventType> events;
                _eventQueue.getAllAndClear(std::back_insert_iterator(events));
                state = _gameLogic.updateState(state, simulationTimeStep, events.cbegin(), events.cend());
                _stateStore.setState(state);
                ++simulationSteps;
            }

            auto lag = (simulationSteps * framePeriod) - durationFromStart();
            if (lag > std::chrono::microseconds{0})
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(lag);

            if (_stop)
                break;
        }
    }

    void sendEvent(EventType e) {
        _eventQueue.push(std::move(e));
    }

    void stop() {
        _stop = true;
    }

    const StateStoreType &stateStore() const {
        return _stateStore;
    }

private:
    static constexpr int frameRate{60};
    static constexpr std::chrono::microseconds framePeriod{1'000'000 / frameRate};
    static constexpr double simulationTimeToRealTime = 1.0;
    static constexpr double simulationTimeStep = 1.0 / frameRate / simulationTimeToRealTime;

    using ClockType = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

    GameLogicType _gameLogic;
    StateStoreType _stateStore;
    detail::Queue<EventType> _eventQueue;
    std::atomic<bool> _stop{false};
};
```

Helper classes:

```
namespace detail {

   /**
    * Event queue for cross-thread data exchange
    */

    template<typename T>
    class Queue {

    public:
        void push(T &&value) {
            std::lock_guard guard{_mtx};
            _queue.push_back(std::forward<T>(value));
        }

        template<typename OutputIt>
        void getAllAndClear(OutputIt outBegin) {
            std::lock_guard guard{_mtx};
            for (auto &e: _queue) // no exception safety for now... caller must be careful
                *outBegin++ = std::move(e);

            _queue.clear();
        }

    private:
        std::deque<T> _queue;
        mutable std::mutex _mtx;
    };

}

/**
 * state container used for cross-thread data exchange
 */
template<typename StateType>
class StateStore {

public:
    void setState(const StateType &state) {
        std::lock_guard guard{_mtx};
        _state = state;
    }

    StateType state() const {
        std::lock_guard guard{_mtx};
        return _state;
    }

private:
    StateType _state;
    mutable std::mutex _mtx;
};
```

A minimal game logic implementation would be:

```
struct SimpleState {
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct SimpleEvent {
    double sx;
    double sy;
};

class SimpleGameLogic {
public:

    using StateType = SimpleState;
    using EventType = SimpleEvent;

    explicit SimpleGameLogic(const StateType &initialState) : _initialState{initialState} {

    }

    StateType initialState() {
        return _initialState;
    }

    template<typename EventInputIt>
    SimpleState updateState(const SimpleState &state, double timeStep, EventInputIt eventsBegin, EventInputIt eventsEnd) {
        (void) timeStep;
        SimpleState newState{state};
        std::for_each(eventsBegin, eventsEnd, [&newState](const SimpleEvent &event) {
            newState.x = newState.x + event.sx;
            newState.y = newState.y + event.sy;
        });
        return newState;
    }

private:
    StateType _initialState;
};
```

The GUI thread interacts with the event loop as follows:

```
 // ...
 using MyEventLoop = EventLoop<SimpleGameLogic>;
 std::unique_ptr<MyEventLoop> eventLoop;
 std::thread eventLoopThread;
 // ...

 void my_gui_init() {
    eventLoop = std::make_unique<MyEventLoop>(SimpleGameLogic{});
    eventLoopThread = std::thread(&MyEventLoop::run, eventLoop.get());
 }

 void my_gui_quit() {
    eventLoop->stop();
    eventLoopThread.join();
 }

 void my_gui_user_input_handler(MyGuiInputType input) {
    MyEventLoop::EventType event = mapUserInput(input);
    eventLoop->sendEvent(event);
 }

 void my_gui_update_method() {
    my_gui_render(eventLoop->state());
 }
```

Comment: Many gaming keyboards scan for input at 1000 Hz or more. Does this code reduce the handling of that input to 60 Hz? Not that that is necessarily bad, but I hope it would be on purpose if it is the case :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks for your comment. The frequency of the loop is in principle arbitrary. If we assume the game logic is too heavy to keep up with 1000Hz then the high-freq input would accumulate in the queue and processed in batch every time step... or at least that's my thinking as a non-expert in this field.

Comment: What is the declaration of `eventLoop` within `my_gui_init`?

Comment: @Edward See the re-worked version.

Comment: There is still a problem because now `eventLoop` is local to `my_gui_init()` and inaccessible to the other functions.  It would clarify your intent for the code if you make your example into something that actually compiles.

Comment: @Edward Sorry, my edit was sloppy. I think it should make more sense now. Keep in mind that the GUI part is intentionally pseudo-code. I think a concrete GUI implementation would be quite out of scope here.